# wrong position of tile map when i convert to retina display

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I follow guide of converting tile map for retina display by changing size of width and height to double size and position of object too.
but the result on normal display is not same as retina display normal display is correct but retina display is not correct

This is non-retina tile map
[image]

and this is retina tile map
[image]

I also add -hd suffix to retinal .tmx file

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Me also observed same problem with cocos2D tile map and finally resolved by dividing CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR. In retina mode it gives 2.0.

```
CCTMXObjectGroup *objects = [tileMap objectGroupNamed:NN_TILE_MAP_OBJECT_LAYER];

CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

NSMutableDictionary *newtonPos = [objects objectNamed:NN_NEWTON_POS];        

if(newtonPos)
{
    float x = ([[newtonPos valueForKey:@"x"] floatValue])/CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    float y = [[newtonPos valueForKey:@"y"] floatValue]/CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();

    MyGameScreen *p = (MyGameScreen*)self.parentLayer;
    p.gameActor.position = ccp(x, y);
}
```

//I used this function to get chord..

```
- (CGPoint)getTileCoordForPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    int maxTileCol = self.mapSize.height; 

    int x = ( (position.x-self.position.x)/TILE_SIZE);
    int y = maxTileCol - ( ((position.y)-self.position.y)/TILE_SIZE);

    if( x >= TILE_IN_ROW)
        x = TILE_IN_ROW - 1;

    if( y >= TILE_IN_COL)
        y = TILE_IN_COL - 1;

    return ccp(x, y);

}
```

Comment: yup, tilemap coords is one of the few places where cocos2d does not convert coords automatically.

Comment: @aratn0n, to get position of objects in object layer.

Comment: when i draw map in Tiled what size of map i should draw hd or non-hd ?

Comment: above two screenshot s good and I did same way to get hd tileMap, and just modified getTileCoordForPosition function. Ok I can show that