# How to create tiled maps for Retina display?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have created a tile map based game using cocos2d-iphone which works perfect in SD (iPad 1) now I want to port it to retina display to work in iPhone 4 and iPad 3 so I created a tiled map with double the tile size of the SD version map and used a double source image for the tiles, but it won't work in my game and when I run the game in iPhone 4, everything is messed up and nothing behaves the way its expected. How can I create a tiled map for Retina display? please help me. I googled but didn't find anything useful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See screenshot in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837104/wrong-position-of-tile-map-when-i-convert-to-retina-display), u need to change image name, tileWidth and tile height, image size..That's it.

Then you get visually good tile map. Some object position problem. For that solution is in same above stack post.

Comment: I did all those things but they didn't work. I override the tileSize method of CCTMXTiledMap class to return half size of the original tile size and now it works!

Comment: @ZeusAlexander, for me its working in all HD versions too...:) ok anyway u got solution too...Happy coding..:)