# Tile map is not Loading in retina disply for ipad

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

For NON retina am using this code Please help how to make for retina disply in ipad

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="21" height="16" tilewidth="49"  tileheight="48">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="FirstLevel-ipad" tilewidth="49" tileheight="48">
  <image source="FirstLevel-ipad.png" width="256" height="256"/>
  <tile id="0">
   <properties>
    <property name="Award" value=""/>
   </properties>
  </tile>
  <tile id="1">
```

For Retina I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="21" height="16" tilewidth="98" tileheight="96">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="FirstLevel-ipadhd" tilewidth="98" tileheight="96">
  <image source="FirstLevel-ipadhd.png" width="512" height="512"/>
  <tile id="0">
   <properties>
    <property name="Award" value=""/>
   </properties>
```

Code related to project

```
_tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"FifthLevel.tmx"];
            [self addChild:_tileMap];
            _objectLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Objects"];
            _dynamicLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Dynamic"];
            //_coinsLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Coins"];
            _keyLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Key"];
            _shadowLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Shadow"];
            _blastedLayer =[_tileMap layerNamed:@"Blasted"];
```

Comment: Can you please add some code about, how you add map into your project?

Comment: _tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"FifthLevel.tmx"];
            [self addChild:_tileMap];
            _objectLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Objects"];
            _dynamicLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Dynamic"];
            _keyLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Key"];
            _shadowLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Shadow"];
            _blastedLayer =[_tileMap layerNamed:@"Blasted"];

Comment: checkout this once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837104/wrong-position-of-tile-map-when-i-convert-to-retina-display/12840642#12840642

Answer (score 1):

In this, the problem is your map's width,it is greater than maximum supported width that is 2048. You can check this error in Logs.

Maximum supported size of TMX map in retina display is **2048*2048**

Comment: Am running my game in landSCAPE MODE

Comment: Do you getting any error in Log??? And it doesn't matter that in which mode you are running your game.